# Chrome print preview breaking Highchart div

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

My problem is that I have a highchart in a div, using dotnethighcharts I am setting the height of the chart container div depending on the number of Y-Axis values. So what happens is the div expands and I scroll down the page to see all of the bars. This is working as intended in Firefox, but in Chrome when I select Print from the Highcharts options dropdown and exit the print preview window, the divs scroll ability breaks and I can't see the whole graph.

I have googled endlessly about this issue and have found nothing that might help. I wonder if there is a way to override the Chrome print preview functionality using javascript, so that when I click Print in the highchart the Chrome print window doesn't open.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
H

Comment: Could you post live example of you issue? Maybe you will be able to change the height of your charts again using afterPrint method? http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.afterPrint
How you are making your chart? Do you have container nested in another container, that is scrollable? Do you set height of both divs?

Comment: Do you receive any errors in the console (developer tools) ?

Comment: The afterPrint method looks promising, any idea how to implement it in dotnetHighcharts?

Comment: and no errors @SebastianBochan

Comment: I would settle at this stage for refreshing the entire page after the print is completed or the print preview is closed. But how do I track this if my chart is created in c# and not js? My brain hurts

Comment: or how to disable the actual print button only, using ExportingButtonsContextButton {}

Comment: I cannot help you with c# if options are different than in JS, but to disable print button in Highcharts you could set different buttons for exporting/context menu. [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems), [demo in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adm3ga6f/)